# How to sub matrix by each column in R

Tags: r, matrix

in R if I have a matrix say:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

is there a fast way to divide this matrix into sub-matrix by each column? After dividing, the left parts are:

```
1
1
1
```

then

```
1 2
1 2
1 2
```

then

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(m1)), function(i) m1[, seq_len(i)])
```